# To pass `echo t | ` as arg in `subprocess.check_output`

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I am new to Python. I am struck up with the below problem.

I have called an exe using subprocess.check_output from my python script.

```
res = subprocess.check_output(["svn.exe", "list", "Https://127.0.0.1:443/svn/Repos"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

when the script is executed in command prompt, i get a prompt message to enter an input,

```
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?
```

But when i execute the script from a batch file, i dont get this message and by default the call `check_output` fails.
Is there any way to pass the input while calling `subprocess.check_output`, so that i could run the script in batch.

Hi, Im updating my question:
I tried to run svn from command prompt with the below command,

```
echo t | svn.exe list Https://127.0.0.1:443/svn/Repos
```

I got the output without any user input.

But i couldnt able to pass the `echo t |` in `subprocess.check_output`.
Is there any way to do this?

Please help me to resolve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions for my problem,

1.found this soultion from this link http://desipenguin.com/techblog/2009/01/13/fun-with-python-subprocessstdin/

```
proc = subprocess.Popen((["svn.exe", "list", "Https://127.0.0.1:443/svn/Repos"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print proc.communicate(‘t\n’)[0]
```

This resolved providing key input 't' to the process. But i was not able to read the output. So, i followed the second solution.

2.Using two subprocesses:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("echo t |", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["svn.exe", "list", "Https://127.0.0.1:443/svn/Repos"], shell=True, **stdin=p.stdout**, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
output = p1[0]
```

Here the output of process 1 is given as input of process 2. So this is equal to `echo t | svnmucc mkdir d:\temp`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not the answer to the question in title, but did you try running `svn` with `--non-interactive --trust-server-cert`? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Hi @Michael I tried adding `"--non-interactive", "--trust-server-cert"`, but i get an error that _Server certificate verification failed_. So it would be helpful, if you could tell me how to pass input for `(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently?`, so that i can make svn accept the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

The message you're getting looks related to certificates to me.  So rather than adding the complication of passing input to the command either fix the certificate problem or pass [the `--trust-server-cert` flag](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw) to the SVN command.

```
res = subprocess.check_output(["svn.exe", "--trust-server-cert", "list", "url"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Yes, the message is related to certificates. Even if i add `"--trust-server-cert"`, i get an error that _Server certificate verification failed_. So it would be helpful, if you could be tell me how to pass input, so that i can make svn accept the certificate.